# Can I use a TimeSpan as an optional parameter with a default value?

Tags: c#, parameters, default, timespan, c#-7.0

The answer for C# 4.0 doesn't work anymore. <-- **(Sorry, this is wrong)**

How can I use a TimeSpan as an optional parameter with default value?

```
public static Foo(string myString, TimeSpan maxWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
{
    // do something
}
```

With this code I get the error:

> default parameter must be a compile-time constant

Comment: What do you mean by "the answer for C# 4 doesn't work anymore"?

Comment: @EvK I missed one `?` from an other SO example. Therefore it didn't work. :/ Therefore I close this post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has never worked in any C# version. Defaults must be constants. You have to create an overload to default the value, or make it nullable and default it if the value is `null`.

Option 1:

```
public static Foo(string myString)
{
    Foo(myString, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}

public static Foo(string myString, TimeSpan maxWait)
{
    // do something
}
```

Option 2:

```
public static Foo(string myString, TimeSpan? maxWait = null)
{
    TimeSpan maxWaitNotNull = maxWait ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    // do something
}
```